# Having trouble getting a library working in an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I wanted to create a map generator using [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) and I came over [this library](http://ageeksnotes.blogspot.com/2010/11/fast-java-implementation-fortunes.html) which already had it figured out. So I downloaded it, and tried to import it into eclipse but I don't think I did it correctly. The installation guide is very brief, saying:

> To use it, build it and add the following dependencies to your project:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>be.humphreys</groupId>  
  <artifactId>simplevoronoi</artifactId>  
  <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>  
</dependency>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to do those things, and get it working with eclipse? I would be very grateful!

EDIT: Got it working thanks to user573215, you're the man!

Comment: What is the error shown by Eclipse? Did you compiled your project with maven or ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML code you posted is for the configuration of the "Maven" build tool, which handles dependency resolution for you.

When you never used Maven and you do not need additional libraries as dependencies I recommend let Maven be Maven and just add the library to your eclipse project configuration:

1. Download the jar (or the source code and build it to a jar)
2. Put the file into your project (e.g. in a "lib" directory)
3. Right click on your project and on "build path" and "configure build path"
4. In the upcoming dialog, go to the "libraries" tab
5. Click on "Add jar" and choose the jar file you downloaded in the lib directory.
6. close the dialog with "OK" or so.

Now you should be able to use the classes in the library in your project.

P.S.: I would like to note, that in my opinion Maven needs a little bit of learning. For one project with one library this is not needed. But if you already got the Maven knowledge it is really possible to get advantage of Maven even for single projects. I sometimes use Maven for single projects with just a few dependencies resulting in many small projects and large dependency trees, but high potential reuseability.